# SQL Returned more than one Value

Tags: sql

Im sure this is simple and i will kick myself when i find out but ive been sitting on this
problem for the last hour and im getting annoyed with it, could anyone help me.

So i am trying to enter a DeviceId and ConfigurationId Column the values are the primary keys from a Device table and a Configuration table. Yes thats really all the problem is.

I tried using `(SELECT ID FROM DeviceId)` But that comes up with the error,

`Subquery returned more than 1 value`

Here is the code i am using the `GETDATE()`'s are just place holders at the moment and the C.Values are me shredding some XML into the table.

```
INSERT INTO [Container].[dsc].[DeviceConfiguration]
 ( DateInserted,
  DeviceId,
  ConfigurationId,
  DateRegistered,
  DateRemoved,
  OperatingSystemInstallDate,
  OperatingSystemSerialNumber
 )

SELECT  GETDATE(),
  <This will need to be DeviceId>,
  <This will need to be the ConfigurationId>,
  GETDATE(),
  GETDATE(),
  C.value('@OSInstallDate', 'datetime'),
  C.value('@OSSerialNumber', 'nvarchar(125)')

FROM [test].[HardwareComponent] CROSS APPLY
                                HardwareComponent.ComponentXmlData.nodes('OSData')AS T(C)
  WHERE HardwareComponent.TypeId = 7
```

Edit:
More info sorry,
The 2 columns are set as foreign keys.

```
ALTER TABLE [dsc].[DeviceConfiguration]
    WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeviceConfiguration_Device
    FOREIGN KEY (DeviceId)
    REFERENCES [dsc].[Device](Id);
GO

ALTER TABLE [dsc].[DeviceConfiguration]
    WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DeviceConfiguration_Configuration
    FOREIGN KEY (ConfigurationId)
    REFERENCES [dsc].[Configuration](Id);
GO
```

Comment: SELECT ID FROM DeviceId will retrieve all the IDs from the table DeviceId.

You're missing a WHERE. It really deppends on how you have your tables structured (DeviceId and ConfigurationId) and how you're supposed to get data out of them.

Either that or DeviceId/ConfigurationId is a foreign key and you need to insert the same ID you *just* inserted on those tables.

Comment: thing is i have well over a thousand records going into the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i counted the rows in the previous table i needed,

```
DECLARE @DeviceId = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM .....)

...
...
...
SELECT
      GETDATE(),
      (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Id) % @DeviceId) AS DeviceId,
      ......
```

And that worked, not quite what i was after but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have primary key ID field in DeviceConfiguration table, and than add below lines after your insert query.

Declare @DeviceId int

Declare @ConfigurationId int

SELECT @DeviceId = DeviceId FROM DeviceConfiguration WHERE ID = @@IDENTITY

SELECT @ConfigurationId = ConfigurationId FROM DeviceConfiguration WHERE ID = @@IDENTITY

And modify your select query as below;

SELECT GETDATE(),
 **@DeviceId**,
  **@ConfigurationId**,
  GETDATE(),
  GETDATE(),
  C.value('@OSInstallDate', 'datetime'),
  C.value('@OSSerialNumber', 'nvarchar(125)')

FROM [test].[HardwareComponent] CROSS APPLY
                                HardwareComponent.ComponentXmlData.nodes('OSData')AS T(C)
  WHERE HardwareComponent.TypeId = 7

Comment: Im just getting NULL values from this?

Comment: Fafed around abit and somehow ended up with the number 30,000 in every row for the DeviceId 0.o, But alas i am still turning up nothing for getting both the DeviceId and ColumnId populated from their tabels.

Comment: ohh yeah just realized your query now, sorry for misleading answer you need to get DeviceId from Device Table. In this case it depends on what you really need.

(SELECT ID FROM DeviceId)  this query can not return you single row, which is why it gives 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' error. 
So you need a sing row to use in insert select query. In this case 
you would need smt like this. 
SELECT ID FROM DeviceId WHERE //some clause here